# Removing null/empty values from an array

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm struggling to understand arrays and structs in BigQuery. When I run this query in Standard SQL:

```
with t1 as (
  select 1 as id, [1,2] as orders
  union all
  select 2 as id, null as orders
)
select
  id,
  orders
from t1
order by 1
```

I get this result in json:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "orders": [
      "1",
      "2"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "orders": []
  }
]
```

I want to remove to remove the orders value for id = 2 so that I instead get:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "orders": [
      "1",
      "2"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "2"
  }
]
```

How can I do this? Do I need to add another CTE to remove null values, how?

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "I get this result in json"? do you mean clicking on JSON button in UI? Also, what exactly your goal here? - why you think you want to "eliminate" `"orders": []`?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant Yes, I mean clicking the JSON button in the web UI. I want to eliminate `"orders": []` as I'll have an extremely large JSON file and any storage space savings will be highly beneficial. The `union all` statement is an essential part of the query and cannot be removed.